# Python namespaced class module directory layout

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to create a `User` module which is namespaced `example`, and currently use the directory structure

```
example\__init__.py (Empty file)
example\user.py (Define the class `User`)
```

And in other file I import via

```
from example.user import User
```

It works, but I want to double check if it is the the Pythonic Way to do it.

Comment: IMHO looks good

Comment: Yes, except you should really consider if you really need the module `user` and it wouldn't be easier and sufficient to just have `User` be in the `example` module.

Comment: ＠Felk, the user.py (contains the User class) is in the example folder already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan,

Your approach is good and 100% Pythonic. Just make sure that you have proper comments in the modules you make.

You can refer this [link](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html) for more information.

Comment: Why is `__init__.py` empty? Does it have to be empty?

Comment: `__init.py__` is there just to tell Python interpreter that current dirrectory is a package, so it is usually empty. However, no, it doesn't have to be empty. You can write all the code you want inside, although I would only use it to "conceal" implementation details.

Comment: thats true. __init__.py should be there to tell python interpreter that this python package otherwise it will consider as normal folder. We can anything in the __init__.py and note that its not recommended unless you want it.